# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a ASP.NET web Site (not Web application), using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and "SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database" in my C# Code.

I am able to successfully compile & publish the website to another IIS Web Server, with Operating System Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. I can even test, successfully, this website on the machine I developed it in.

I am publishing the website, from within Visual Studio, to a Network web server running IIS.  To Publish I am using Build-> "Publish Web Site".  In the Publish Profile, I am using Web Deploy Method. Even though I am using, successfully, "SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database" in my website, the "settings" (in Publish Profile) does not detect any Databases in the project. Which may not be a problem.

When I try to bring up the web site on the IIS Web Server machine I get the following error..

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies .

As my project is a Web Site, not Web Site Application, I do not have a references node in the Solution Explorer. I think the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll, which is type GAC in my project, is not getting published to the webserver, which is causing this Error. Can I copy this .dll over manually ? If yes, where to put on the ISS Web Server ? I do not see any bin folder.

Any help to resolve this error will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In the View menu -> Solution Explorer. There you should be able to see the References node.

Comment: I can see the references used in my Project when go to view->Property Pages->References. It shows System.Data.SqlServerCe, GAC, Version 4.0.0.0. So I added this reference. That is how I am able to use the Local DB in my Project, compile. It says Published successfully. But it does not work

Comment: Did you install the SqlServerCe Nuget package? Or did you use the stand-alone installer? If the latter, you need to run the stand-alone installer on each machine where it will be used.

Answer (score 4):

you have to install sql server compact 4.0 on IIS webserver where you are going to deploy application.

download following exe and install it on IIS webserver.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17876

definitely it will be work.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 (SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe) works for me when trying to use CompactView to view `*.sdf databases created by Alfa Ebooks Manager.

See:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/

for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same issue and that's how I solved my problem:

Turned out in some version of windows, there's a different setting for `winTrust` in windows registry:

If you have already installed `SSCERuntime`, go to this address in windows registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing\
```

Check for `State` key. Its value has to be `23c00`.

If its `c9` or somthing else, change it to `23c00` and close the registry.

Hopefully you will pass the issue.
Worked for me.