# @Functions does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2015

I know variations of this issue has been asked and answered. However, this is a specific case in which I have a Functions.cshtml page defined and I have successfully referenced functions found on that page. I've been able to successfully run my web site. However, VS 2015 periodically can't find the Functions.xyz reference when I recall the project in the IDE. Sometimes, I can copy the Functions.cshtml page to another location, then delete it from the project, close out VS, reopen VS and re-add Functions.cshtml back to the project. That in itself does not cause VS to now resolve the problem. I have to then open the Functions.cshtml in the IDE editor and select to build the web site. Then SOMETIMES, VS will then resolve the reference. However, I'm stuck now - VS is completely unable to resolve the reference and need new ideas on how to resolve it. Here is the code samples:
Functions.cshtml:

```
@Functions {

    public static System.Data.DataSet qryGeneralExecute(string query)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString(false).ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            cn.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            cn.Close();

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                return ds;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling page:

```
        {
            bor_studinfoDataSet = Functions.qryGeneralExecute(query);
        }
```

When I run the project, I get `The name 'Functions' does not exist in the current context`.

Any suggestions on resolving this?

Comment: Isn't it `@functions` with a lowercase `f` in Razor?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what happened. Between the time my project was working and now was I went thru a process of correcting a completely unrelated SQL Server Management System (SSMS) issue with inability to log into a SQL instance under strict security circumstances. This involved uninstalling & re-installing SQL several times. In the course of correcting this issue, SQL Server Compact 4.0 was uninstalled though v3.5 was installed. Well evidently this somehow triggered this issue, including what I thought was the unrelated error "could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers', version=3.0.0.0 or one of its dependencies" but appears to be related. I solved this helpers error by doing an update via NuGet of Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (found this solution by Bjorn here - [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, error on IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-helpers-error-on-iis-8) - thanks Bjorn). Once I corrected for this helpers error, this Functions error was solved but I then received the error "could not load file or assembly system.data.sqlserverce, version=4.0.0.0 or one of its dependencies". Searching for its solution, I was led to [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192275/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlserverce-version-4-0-0-0#26466137). From there, I then proceeded to download and install MS SQL Compact v4.0 and this last error was eliminated. The project now compiles and I can run my app.